# Does maxima have column and row names for matrices?

Tags: maxima, col

does maxima have a colnames and rownames property for matrices (that would be shown in a print statement)?  (aka, colnames(m) in R)

I suspect not, but wanted to make sure.  this would make it more convenient for a function to return different types of numbers, which the matrix can then collect by row and print with name.

Comment: No, there isn't an analogue of `colnames` in Maxima. Maybe it works well enough to just put the names into the matrix, i.e. first row are all symbols or strings, and/or first column.

Comment: please just answer not as a comment, and I can click solved.  gets you a point or two, also ;-).